# Changing or to our

Tags: java

I've been working on a program for school for some time now that is supposed to change every word that ends in "or" and does not have a vowel before the "or". However I am running into an issue where it replaces the letters for words such as paper and letter into papeur and letteur. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        //Initializing Variables
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] vowels = new char[] {'a','e','i','o','u'};
        boolean hasVowel = false;
        boolean running = true;
        boolean oR = false;

        while(running){
            //Check for word
            System.out.println("Enter a word more than 4 letters long or type quit to stop");
            String word = input.nextLine();
            if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
                System.exit(0);
            }
                while(word.length() <= 4){
                    System.out.println("That word is not more than 4 letters long");
                    word = input.next();
                }

                //Used to insert words
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(word);

                //Check for the letters
                char x = word.charAt(word.length()-2);
                if(word.endsWith("r")){
                    if(x == 'o') {
                        oR = true;
                        System.out.println("Has or");
                        for (char c : vowels) {
                            if (c == word.charAt(word.length() - 3)) {
                                hasVowel = true;
                                oR = false;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


                //output
                if (hasVowel){
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
                else{
                    if(oR = true) {
                        stringBuilder.insert(word.length() - 1, "u");
                        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
                    }
                    else if (oR = false) {
                        System.out.println(word);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(hasVowel);
                System.out.println(word.charAt(word.length()-3));

            }
        }
}
```

If someone could help me out that would be amazing!

Comment: Use regexes, might be less performant but will be easier to write out and less chance of failure.

Comment: You may need to review your transformation rules because they convert `for` to `four`, `doctor -> doctour, donor -> donour, error -> errour, sailor -> sailour, pastor -> pastour` and many more and do NOT convert `behavior, savior`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this line:

```
if(oR = true) {
```

This will always be `true`, because it is an assignment rather than an equality check.  You want `==` here.

Also note that the `else` clause that goes with this:

```
else if (oR = false) {
```

can be just:

```
else {
```

since if a boolean value isn't `true`, it has to be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can edit

```
public static void main(String[] args){


    //Initializing Variables
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] vowels = new char[] {'a','e','i','o','u'};
    boolean hasVowel = false;
    boolean running = true;
    boolean oR = false;

    while(running){
        //Check for word
        System.out.println("Enter a word more than 4 letters long or type quit to stop");
        String word = input.nextLine();
        if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
            while(word.length() <= 4){
                System.out.println("That word is not more than 4 letters long");
                word = input.next();
            }

            //Used to insert words
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(word);

            //Check for the letters
            char x = word.charAt(word.length()-2);
            if(word.endsWith("r")){
                if(x == 'o') {
                    oR = true;
                    System.out.println("Has or");
                    for (char c : vowels) {
                        if (c == word.charAt(word.length() - 3)) {
                            hasVowel = true;
                            oR = false;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            //output
            if (hasVowel){
                System.out.println(word);
            }
            else{
                if(oR) { //if(oR == true)
                    stringBuilder.insert(word.length() - 1, "u");
                    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
                }
                else { //else if (!oR) //else if (oR == false) 
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(hasVowel);
            System.out.println(word.charAt(word.length()-3));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this task could be resolved using regular expressions because it is a natural way of searching and replacing substrings in strings.

The basic regular expression to replace suffix `-or` with suffix `-our` on the condition that `-or` is not preceded by a vowel is as follows:

```java
public String simpleOrToOur(String word) {
    return word.replaceAll("(\\w+[^aeiou])or", "$1our");
}
```

However, the initial rule does not seem to be correct because the replacements should NOT occur in multiple cases when there is a consonant *before* `or`, and may occur *for* `-ior` prefix:

- `bor`: no `rubour`
- `cor`: no `decour, mucour`, only `rancour/succour`
- `dor`: only `ardour, candour, odour, splendor` are valid, no replacement needed in `dor, condor, corridor, vendor`, etc.
- `for`: is not replaced with `four`
- `gor`: only `clangour, rigour, vigour`, and no replacement in: `mortgagor, pledgor, turgor`
- `hor`: not replaceable at all: `anchor, author, camphor,` etc.
- `ior`: **vowel** need to replace in `behavior, pavior, savior`
- `lor`: no replacement needed in `bachelor, chancellor, counsellor, jailor, sailor, tailor` etc.
- `mor`: actually it should be `a[r]mor` or `umor` as in `armor, clamor, glamor, humor`, no replacement in `mor, tremor`
- `nor`: replacement needed only in `honor, demeanor` and their derivatives, no replacement in `donor, manor, minor, signor, tenor`, etc.
- `por`: needed in `sapor, vapor`, not in `stupor, torpor`
- `vor`: should be `avor/ervor` as in `flavor, fervor`, not in `salvor, survivor`

Other prefixes with remaining consonants `[jkqstwxyz]or` do not need replacement to `-our` either.

That being said, a better matching regexp consisting of prefix including the mentioned subparts joined with OR `|` and suffix `-or` may be implemented:

```java
public static String changePrefixOrToOur(String word) {
    return word.replaceAll("(((h?ar|[lt]a|neigh)b)|(ranc|succ)|((ar|can|o|splen)d)|((clan|[rv]i)g)|(vi)|(([cd]o|par|va)l)|((ar?|u)m)|((ho|demea)n)|([sv]ap)|((a|er)v))or",
        "$1our"
);
}
```

Test:

```java
String[] replaceableWords = {
    "arbor", "harbor", "neighbor", "labor", "tabor",
    "rancor", "succor",
    "ardor", "candor", "odor", "splendor",
    "clangor", "vigor", "rigor",
    "misbehavior", "pavior", "savior",
    "color", "dolor", "parlor", "valor",
    "amor", "armor", "tumor", "humor", "clamor", "glamor",
    "dishonor", "honor", "misdemeanor",
    "vapor", "sapor",
    "flavor", "endeavor", "favor", "savor", "disfavor"
};

int successCount = 0;
for (String word : replaceableWords) {
    String replaced = changePrefixOrToOur(word);
    successCount += replaced.endsWith("our") ? 1 : 0;
    //System.out.printf("%s -> %s ? %s%n", word, replaced, replaced.endsWith("our") ? "OK" : "FAIL");
}

System.out.printf("Replaced  `or` to `our`: %d of %d words%n---%n%n", successCount, replaceableWords.length);

String[] notReplaceableWords = {
    "rubor",
    "decor", "mucor",
    "ambassador", "condor", "corridor", "conquistador", "dor", "matador", "picador", "vendor",
    "meteor",
    "for",
    "mortgagor", "pledgor", "turgor", "tangor",
    "abhor", "anaphor", "anchor", "author", "camphor", "metaphor",
    "anterior", "prior", "superior", "warrior",
    "Angkor",
    "bachelor", "counselor", "chancellor", "squalor", "tailor", "sailor", "taylor",
    "mor", "tremor",
    "nor", "assignor", "donor", "governor", "signor", "minor", "manor", "tenor", "intervenor",
    "door", "floor", "moor", "outdoor", "poor", "boor",
    "por", "sopor", "torpor", "stupor",
    "advisor", "censor", "professor", "processor", "sensor", "tensor",
    "actor", "doctor", "director", "factor", "bettor",
    "liquor", "languor", "fluor",
    "survivor", "salvor",
    "xor", "luxor", "taxor",
    "mayor",
    "razor", "seizor", "vizor"
};

for (String word : notReplaceableWords) {
    String replaced = changePrefixOrToOur(word);
    successCount += replaced.endsWith("or") ? 1 : 0;
    //System.out.printf("%s -> %s ? %s%n", word, replaced, replaced.endsWith("or") ? "OK" : "FAIL");
}
System.out.printf("Not replaced  `or` to `our`: %d of %d words%n", successCount - replaceableWords.length, notReplaceableWords.length);
```

Output:

```
Replaced `or` to `our`: 37 of 37 words
---

Not replaced  `or` to `our`: 79 of 79 words
```